# How does "shouldinterceptrequest" block some URLs?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a small ad block android app that can deny getting resources of webview contents from predefined(denied) domains.

*mainly to deny .js requests not to load ads to the website*

```
@Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        if (url.contains("www.example.com")) {
            return false; // want to block loading resource from this domain
        } 
    }
```

I found some examples, but I am still not solved. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    if (url.contains("www.example.com")) {
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "UTF-8", null);
    } 
}
```

Also you can follow bellow code

```
    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://Your_website_url")) {
         // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
         return false;
    }

    // reject anything other
    return true;
}
}
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());  //set the webviewClient
```

Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url.